Up and Down prepositions with the same meaning as "to" preposition of direction
My questions in basically how does this form of usage of these prepositions work within this context? i have been reading all the way long that this is one of the senses that "Up" and "Down" can have and i really want to know a bit more of it as to the way it works.
Ex. "did you go up the pub yesterday?"
NOTE:
I do acknowledge "Down" is used for expressing the sense of a place which is located away from another one without specifying all by itself.

This question is similar to: Is the preposition optional in "going down (to) the store"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // 'Going up the shops' etc I'd say are unidiomatic or at best slang.

It's in Merriam-Webster: ": up into or in the", and the OED has similar as well as "up at"; this is variously labeled as "US" or "colloquial and dialect", with the OED having a series of examples from London. So what dialect or region are you interested in? Where did you hear "go up the pub"? What exactly are you interested in? I could just copy a bunch of stuff from the OED but there doesn't seem much point to that.
